# unable to install homebrew

Tags: macos, command-line, homebrew, open-source

unable to install homebrew
I am using this command.

```
ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"
```

getting this error. i have already installed updated command line tool

[image]

[image]

Comment: The error message includes a suggestion to update via **Apple (menu) > App Store…**. What do you see in **App Store.app** under the **Updates** tab?

Comment: i have already updated Command line tool. check updated second image.

Comment: What does `/usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path` show? I've deleted my answer since you don't need any software updates and you might only need to run `sudo /usr/bin/xcode-select -r` if you don't get the correct directory listing from the print path command. From what I can tell,your script can't find a git binary and is asking for the developer tools to be installed yet you already have them installed.

Comment: Have you [opened an issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues) with homebrew themselves? Maybe someone there has seen this before.

Comment: i have not installed xcode. is that a problem?

Comment: @user3595194 No - you don't need Xcode. You could try installing it if your  want. It might get enough `git` for the homebrew to complete installing or throw a more intelligible error to you for action...

Comment: i got it. just uninstall command line tool than let it install with brew. i think there is bug with brew installation command.

Answer (score 1):

From your output, it looks like the developer tools version of `git` is missing. You could uninstall Xcode (delete it) and try again a manual install of just the tools **homebrew** needs.

I prefer to install the command line tools as follows:

- Have an admin user/password handy - you don't need to be logged in as an admin - just know the password
- `/usr/bin/xcode-select --install`

That should either error if you have Xcode already installed or command line tools. If you don't have the necessary tools - it will download and ask for installation.

Please note - the Mac App store is having issues right now - you might be doing everything right and need to wait for the server issues to get sorted:

- http://www.apple.com/support/systemstatus/

[image]

To get past the check you are running into, the command below needs to return a good match that git is **Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64**:

```
file $(/usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path)/usr/bin/git
```

Comment: file $(/usr/bin/xcode-select -print-path)/usr/bin/git
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/git: Mach-O 64-bit executable x86_64